# Number of shoes to be taken out.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $7$ pairs of black shoes and $5$ pairs of white shoes. 
>   They are all put into a box and shoes are drawn one at a time. 
>   To ensure that at least one pair of black shoes are taken out, 
>   what is the number of shoes required to be drawn out ?

$a.)\ 12 \\
b.)\ 13 \\
c.)\ 7 \\
\color{green}{d.)\ 18 }$

I did the worst case

$ww,\ ww,\ ww,\ ww,\ ww,\ bb $

$=12$ shoes.

But the answer given in book is $d.) $

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there are left and right shoes. Therefore the worst case is all $10$ white shoes as well as seven left black shoes. You've taken out seventeen shoes, and you don't have a black pair.

On the other hand, if you've taken out $18$ shoes, then there can only be $6$ shoes left in the box, which means you must have taken out a black pair at some point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  In the case you described there are two black shoes, but they might not be a **pair** of black shoes....

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the question means that a pair is one left shoe and one right shoe, so you can take all the whites (10) and all the left (or right) blacks (another 7) and still have no pair.